# What does "TypeError: connect() got multiple values for argument 'dsn'" with python-oracledb mean?

Tags: python, database, oracle, python-oracledb

The [python-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/) code:

```
import oracledb
import os

un = os.environ.get("PYTHON_USERNAME")
pw = os.environ.get("PYTHON_PASSWORD")
cs = "localhost/orclpdb1"

c = oracledb.connect(un, pw, dsn=cs)
```

fails with the error:

```
TypeError: connect() got multiple values for argument 'dsn'
```

How do I fix this?

Update: in python 1.0.0 the error was `TypeError: wrapped() got multiple values for argument 'dsn'`  In 1.0.1 the `wrapped()` was replaced by the connect or create pool function name used in the application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to consistently use keyword parameters:

```
c = oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs)
```

or

```
pool = oracledb.create_pool(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs, min=4, max=4, incr=1)
```

The `oracledb.connect()` and `oracledb.create_pool()` (and deprecated
`oracledb.SessionPool()`) parameters are keyword, not positional. This complies
with the Python Database API spec [PEP 249](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/).